# Can't start Git in OS X El Capitan

Tags: git, macos, osx-elcapitan

I upgrated my os x from mavericks to EL Capitan and when want to use git in android studio, i got this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Maybe same problem as over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299615/cant-connect-to-git-repo-on-el-capitan-with-sourcetree?rq=1

Comment: tnx, Your answer and also @Muhammad Ali 's solution is work fine for me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See this solution:

After updating Mac OS X to ‘El Capitan’, my local git command was not working anymore. When using the git command, the command line returns:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

The solution to fix this is to reinstall the command line developer tools using this command:

xcode-select --install

Answer (score 2):

Faced this after upgrading to El-Capitan

```
xcode-select --install
```

didn't work for me even after 'Finding Software' and Downloading. I don't have Xcode.app installed (Didn't want to install it) so i fixed it by downloading [Command Line Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjS3f.png) from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (requires Apple SignIn) and installed it manually.

After installation i was able to run `git` commands again

Answer (score 2):

**xcode-select --install** run on your terminal

it works for  me